# How to implement a AngularJS Google Images style rows with center content bar

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angular app with rows of four boxes followed by a sliding div that opens and displays information from the above boxes. I first tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(i % 4 == 0) components.push([]);
    components[components.length-1].push(data[i]);
  }
  return $scope.components = components;
});
```

Using nested ng-repeats I would push 4 in then the bar would be put in then rinse and repeat. I could use `$parent` to push info into the sliding div and just the bar below the row would open and populate. When I tried using the filtering with this method it would filter out per row but would leave the number of rows intact. So I tried using a single ng-repeat with a switch case to add the bar every 4. The filtering works now but the scoping figures out to the sliding bar being the child of the box in the row and using `$parent`. now opens and populates all the sliding divs.

If I'm not doing a good job describing what I'm trying to do think of google images and the bar that pops up in-between rows of images. Except instead of having varying number per line I always have four.

I can make my own filters from scratch and apply them inside the controller before I use the first method I tried but I feel like there must be an easier way

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the ng-animate for the slide out to you, but here's a basic directive that should point you in the right direction. (I didn't test this code, so there might be typos.)  Remember, if you're doing UI components, you want to be using a directive.

```
module.directive('slidePanel', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
      cards:'='
    },
    template:'<div>
        <div class="cardrow">
          <div ng-repeat="c in cards" class="card-panel">
            {{c.cardTitle}}
            <button ng-click="openCard(c)">Open</button>
            <!-- html for each card here ->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carddetail" ng-show="activeCard">
            {{activeCard.title}}
            <!-- html for card detail here-->
        </div>
      </div>',
    link: function(scope,el,attrs) {
      scope.activeCard = null;
      scope.openCard = function(c) {
        scope.activeCard = c;
      }
    }

  }
});

<slide-panel cards='cardVariableFromMyController'></slide-panel>
```

Comment: In this answer you just show the detail in .carddetail div. I guess that's a css problem with angular. I have a problem like that, but I couldn't imagine where to put the detail box.